# RadioGroup listener dont work

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, radio-group

I have a `Fragment` that displays a `Dialog`.
Inside that `Dialog` there is a `RadioGroup`.
I tried to create a listener to this `RadioGroup`, but i didn't successed.

`Fragment` --> `Dialog` --> `RadioGroup`

I tried four ways:

1. `OnCheckedChangeListener` on `RadioGroup`.
2. `OnClickListener` on `RadioGroup`.
3. `OnCheckedChangeListener` on `RadioButton`.
4. `OnClickListener` on `RadioButton`

No one worked.

Here is my code:

The `Dialog` - layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/bS_rg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ID"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_genre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Genre"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/r_author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Author"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/c_bSearch"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `Fragment` - layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.codecrafters.tableview.TableView
        android:id="@+id/tableView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `Fragment` - code: (I marked where is the problem, the other code is not important)

```
package com.example.adiel.library_app_30;

import .....;

public class ShowAllBooks extends Fragment {
    View v;
    TableLayout table;
    TableRow row;
    String[] spaceProbeHeaders = {"ID", "Title"};
    String[][] spaceProbes;
    AutoCompleteTextView c_search;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_all_books, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        /*
        ------The problem is here----
        */
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext());
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.b_search_dialog, null);
        c_search = (AutoCompleteTextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.c_bSearch);
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.bS_rg);
        rg.check(R.id.r_id);

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                Log.d("Log", "Clicked");
            }
        });

        rg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Log", "Clicked");
            }
        });
        RadioButton r_id = (RadioButton) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.r_id);
        r_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.d("Log", "Clicked");
            }
        });
        r_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Log", "Clicked");
            }
        });
        /*
        ------Until here----
        */


        final TableView<String[]> tb = (TableView<String[]>) v.findViewById(R.id.tableView);
        tb.setColumnCount(2);
        tb.setHeaderBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2ecc71"));

        Ask a = new Ask("books", "getAllCopiesOfBooks", null);
        Client client = (Client) new Client(a, a.getIp(), v.getContext(), new Client.ClientReply() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(Object output) {
                if (output != null) {
                    ArrayList<CopyId> data = (ArrayList<CopyId>) output;
                    spaceProbes = new String[data.size()][2];
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                        CopyId c = data.get(i);
                        spaceProbes[i][0] = String.valueOf(c.getId());
                        spaceProbes[i][1] = c.getTitle();
                    }
                    tb.setHeaderAdapter(new SimpleTableHeaderAdapter(v.getContext(), spaceProbeHeaders));
                    tb.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(v.getContext(), spaceProbes));
                }
            }
        }).execute();

        tb.addDataClickListener(new TableDataClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataClicked(int rowIndex, Object clickedData) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ((String[]) clickedData)[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShowBook.class);
                i.putExtra("id", ((String[]) clickedData)[0]);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.showallbooks_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_add:

                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:
                search_func();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void search_func(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(v.getContext());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.b_search_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Search");
        dialog.show();




        //RadioButton r_id = (RadioButton) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.r_id);
        /*RadioButton r_title = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.r_title);
        RadioButton r_genre = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.r_genre);
        RadioButton r_author = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.r_author);*/



    }
}
```

Comment: Keep only this listener `rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()` and remove other listeners and try.

Comment: Still not working